# Copy/Paste issues with chrome apps for non English input methods

Tags: mac, mojave, google-chrome, input-source

When using any chrome app while on a non-English input, Copy&Paste shortcuts aren't working.

When using the same web app via browser tabs or any other Mac app, there's no issue.

When switching input to English, the shortcuts are working.

Comment: Please provide the names of a specific app and input source so others can easily test the issue.

Comment: WhatsApp web, Google Messages.
However, It doesn't matter which chrome app I'm using, it won't let me copy or paste when using a non English input method.

Comment: To reproduce, use chrome menu to "create shortcut" and "open as a window", then, switch input method and try to paste, you'll experience the issue, when you'll switch back, you can paste again.

I use Hebrew as a second language for example.